# Red Cross Ambulance Network Monitoring

Tags: windows, windows-10, gps, portable

Hello from Red Cross Germany!

We have 30+ Ambulances and 30+ Windows 10 Tablets with LTE/Cellular

We are looking for a solution to Monitor Our Cellular LTE Coverage in certain Areas where are ambulances go to. We use Vodafone LTE and our goal is to see the signal strength of each area our ambulances go to. Preferable with GPS Map and Coverage or something that logs GPS, Signal Strength and anything more!

We can't switch to Android become our Tablets have some Red Cross Tools that only work with Windows 10

We don't want to see the bandwidth, nor the data: Just the Signal Strength. I've seen many products that can do that with Android, iPhone but Windows 10 seems hard to find an App for!

Free would be better but something cheap is fine too.

Thank you!